# Xcode Playground - Live view dimensions (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground, liveview

I am setting dimension of live view in Xcode using

```
view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 900, height: 675))
```

And I am getting this in the live view, 
[Screenshot - 900 X 675](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH8rS.png)

Where each square is 100 X 100, to compare the dimensions.
So, instead of getting a view of 900 X 675, I am getting a view of around 700(something) X 675.

Another example,

```
view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600))
```

[Screenshot - 800 X 600](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVA1O.png)

So, is this a bug with Xcode Playground or am I doing something wrong?
I am using the code below to set up the live view.

```
import PlaygroundSupport   
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600))   
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

EDIT: Complete Code - https://docs.google.com/document/d/18zIHo10fb5PuYpmrSVnqa2480PgGrBvtiexgugw8fms/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have tried your code, It's working fine. I'm using XCode 9.0

Comment: I am working on XCode 9.2 and tried it on 2 different Macs. Have the same problem.

Comment: Can you post code which draw square of 100x100 in your main view ?

Comment: It's not a bug with Xcode or you are doing something wrong. The size of the live view on the playground is matched with iPad 9.7 dimension, which is 768x1024.

Comment: Would you mind trying this code
https://docs.google.com/document/d/18zIHo10fb5PuYpmrSVnqa2480PgGrBvtiexgugw8fms/edit?usp=sharing

And sharing the screenshot.